# Removing An Active Class From Mootools Tabs

Tags: tabs, mootools

I'm ploughing ahead in my attempts to learn Mootools (damn, I miss Consider Open's 30 days tutorials) and I'm trying to build a simple class switching script. I've found one on this very site that does the trick, but ideally I'd like to be able to remove all instances of .active from the li elements, if you click on the currently active element.

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m66Ju/1/)  if anyone fancies taking a look at the problem.

I did take a look at the documentation on the mootools site, but I'm afraid I still couldn't get a handle on which section would help me with this. I am keen to learn how to do this stuff myself, so I'd be greatful for not just the solution, but a pointer to the parts of the mootools documentation I should have been looking at to crack this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aside from performance, your code is fine. by performance, I mean - it should not have to go to the dom on every click to get the list of elements or the current active one to do what it needs to do - all that can be cached. your code will run against any .active in a collection, which initially will have .length of 0 so on first click nothing will happen. the performance issue is having to select all elements again and ones with .active, then running a .each on them for the single member that can have it.

you could do something like this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/m66Ju/2/

```
(function() {
    var ul = document.getElement("ul.examples"), lis = ul.getElements("li"), active;
    lis.addClass('transition');

    lis.each(function(item){
        item.addEvent('click',function(event){
            if (active) {
                // there is one, remove it.   
                active.removeClass('active');
            }
            if (active == this) {
                // is the active one already open?
                active = false;
                return;
            }
            // make a new active.
            active = this.addClass('active');
        });
    });
})();
```

this will be most performant and will work with an initial active li as well.

there is no manual on how to structure your code for performance and reuse, but there are a few talks that may help, like Aaron Newton's Programming to Patterns (with mootools) etc. Rule of thumb is, don't do premature optimisation but code so the slowest supported browser (usually IE6 or 7) works as fast as possible. click events afford some leeway but mouseover ones can be expensive.

Comment: Cheers for that, Dimitar, I'll be sure to take a look at the talk you mentioned. Any idea how I can remove all active classes when clicking the active link though? That's what I'm struggling against at the minute. Cheers.

Comment: you did so already - you can do `ul.getElements("li.active").removeClass("active");` - which you kind of did by using `$$(".examples .active").removeClass("active")` - does it not work for you? since I figured only one can be .active there was no need to go to selector as you can store which one.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm at a point where I know what the code snippet does, but I'm unsure of where it fits into the syntax to make it work.I've tried adding it where I think it should go, but I'm not getting any result. Sorry to be such a noob about it, but could I trouble you for a working example?

Comment: that's what i mean, both of these work fine - my edited version and your original - they remove the .active class and then add a new one to the clicked el. not sure what your expectation is?

Comment: Hey, no sorry, I've clearly not explained my goal well enough.

What I'm looking for, is that when you click the currently active link, it removes all .active classes from the li elements, including the one being clicked, so that everything reverts back to a pre-clicked state, and no elements show as active.

Comment: it does just that already. when you do `$$('.examples .active').removeClass('active');` it will remove the class from any and all elements it finds, so you really had no errors as such, just performance. my code simply caches it all so you don't do lookups - is all. but your original works.

Comment: Okay, well this is weird then, because when I click the active class, nothing happens. You've already been extremely generous with your time and knowledge, so I don't wish to bother you further with this. I'll ask a few colleagues if they can test the example and figure out what's happening.

Comment: it works here in FF 7. if it does not seem to do anything, it may be to do with the transition. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/m66Ju/3/ - is that ok for you?

Comment: I'm on the latest version of Safari (Mac) and I'm afraid that's the same. It switches the active class without problem, but when you click the active class, nothing happens, it just remains active.

Comment: that's correct. clicking on the active class should not change it? or rather, it changes it (removes it) and then adds it again. is that not your desired behaviour? you want it to removeClass and exit if it has it (i.e. fold)

Comment: Ahh yes, you see this is where I think we've got our wires crossed. Yes indeed, when clicking the active state, I'd like it to remove the .active class, and not re-add it, essentially, re-setting the page to how it was before anything was clicked.

Of course if any of the links are clicked again, I'd like the active class to be applied as shown in the example, but essentially, what I'd like is clicking the active class to function as a 'reset button' so that all the links reset to their original state, and no active states are shown.

Comment: no worries. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/m66Ju/5/ - if active is a pointer to an element, it removes the class and exits. in your original code, you can save it in a variable eg `var active = $$(".active"); if (active.length) { active.removeClass("active"); return; }`

Comment: Dimitar, you're a star. Seriously, thanks so much for sticking with this, and sorry if my original description wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

So, your problem can be decomposed in two phases:

1. Selecting your target `li` elements.
2. Remove the `active` class.

Remember that MooTools is object-oriented. So, which objects will you be working on? DOM elements. That means you should take a look at MooTools' [`Element` documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element).

For selecting, you're looking for the [`Element.getElements` method](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3agetElements) (or `$$`).

Then, for removing a class… Well, simply [`Element.removeClass`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3aremoveClass)  ;)

So, your code should look something like:

```
$$('li.active').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: @Dimitar: connexion down right before I was about to post. Sorry for doubling your answer, yadah yadah.

Comment: Yup, got it, thanks for the explanation and the links to the Moo documentation, that really helps.